# Why doesn't the silverlight plugin quit after I close a Netflix tab in my browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, silverlight

When I close a Netflix tab on my browser (Chrome), the Silverlight plugin process stays running. I can quit it manually using Activity Monitor (I'm on OS X), but it would be nice if it quit on its own, since my computer uses its dedicated graphics card while Silverlight is running, which wastes battery. Is it possible to have Silverlight quit as soon as I close a tab that uses it?

Comment: Why do you need SilverLight running on your dedicated graphics card? Netflix will receive no performance benefit on it and will just use more power. On the other hand, SilverLight (while running on your dedicated) will not use extra power after you've stopped using it. On Windows SilverLight will wait in memory (not using the GPU in the slightest) and when nothing uses SilverLight, SilverLight will garbage collect itself (could take up to 30 minutes).

Comment: @MarkLopez You're absolutely right, but it's not my choice when my computer decides it needs the dedicated card. I understand that Silverlight doesn't use any GPU when it doesn't need to, but my computer decides that while Silverlight is running, the dedicated card needs to be on, even if it's not doing anything. It's stupid, but that's just how it works.

Comment: I know I Windows the user can choose which applications will use the GPU and when. Mac believes that your should never need to. Try a program like this: http://gfx.io/ to force SilverLight off of the GPU. I do not think this is a problem with Chrome or SilverLight (both are running as they are designed), but more will Mac and how it's GPU algorithm works.

Comment: @MarkLopez In fact, I do use gfx. However, when my computer is connected to an external monitor, it switches to the dedicated card regardless of what's running or what I want. When I disconnect it, it should switch back to integrated, except it doesn't when Silverlight stays running. You're absolutely right about Mac's graphics card decision-making being part of the problem, but I think it's also reasonable to expect Silverlight to quit when I close a Netflix tab.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in either Chrome or Silverlight. Usually, the plugin does close/gets closed once you close the Netflix tab. The fact that this doesn't happen indicates a fail in the browser or the plugin itself.

To pinpoint the source of the problem you could try a different browser and see if this fixes the problem. If this is the case then it's a bug in Chrome. If not, then it's Silverlight.

The obvious solution would be to check for updates for both the browser and Silverlight. You could also try to downgrade either one. Knowing when the problem occured first could be the key here. Did you upgrade either components before it happened, or did you install any addons?

Another tip would be to use Chrome's incognito mode. It disables all add-ons. If the problem still exists then you can rule those out.